# Issue with Apache Commons Complex add() function

Tags: java

So basically I am writing an android app and I notice that the add function is not working properly. When I tried testing it with

```
Complex dummy = Complex.ZERO;
        dummy.add(Complex.I);
        Log.i("DEBUG", "DUMMY = " + dummy);
```

I get

```
I/DEBUG: DUMMY = (0.0, 0.0)
```

from Logcat. I can't seem to find what went wrong with such a simple function call.

This is the description of the function from [Apache's website](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/complex/Complex.html#add(org.apache.commons.math3.complex.Complex))

> public Complex add(Complex addend)
>               throws NullArgumentException
>
> Returns a Complex whose value is (this + addend). Uses the definitional formula
>   (a + bi) + (c + di) = (a+c) + (b+d)i

Comment: Hint: "returns a Complex", not "mutates a complex"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex.Zero = (0.0 + 0.0i)

Complex.I = (0.0 + 1.0i)

**Why not?**

The answer is in your question itself(on the docs),

> **Returns** a Complex whose value is (this + addend)

Here `dummy.add(Complex.I);` returns (0.0 + 1.0i) but is not used. So, assign the return value back to `dummy`

Correct code would be

```
dummy = dummy.add(Complex.I);
```

PS: Also, in my 5+ years of coding. I've blindly trusted Apache Commons everyday everytime. Never it failed ;)